# npm ERR! config is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

[image]

getting this Error. I have uninstalled the node and tried to installed again. still getting this error. Using latest version of node.
**Node version** : 20.11.1
**npm version** : 9.6.3

Comment: well maybe you could tell us what you are trying to do when you faced this error

Comment: whenever i am running npm commands like npm install or npm run dev etc.

Comment: What do you see when you run `npm config list`?

Comment: ; "builtin" config from C:\Users\Mayuresh Gage\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc

prefix = "C:\\Users\\Mayuresh Gage\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; node version = v20.11.1
; npm local prefix = D:\React\04bgchanger
; npm version = 10.5.0
; cwd = D:\React\04bgchanger
; HOME = C:\Users\Mayuresh Gage
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.